# DataGrid MUI React renderCell on column definition infinity times re-renders

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I have DataGrid from MUI, and I applied to two columns of my Table RenderCell, ONe is to show Number of Active participants and other to be poper cell to show user involved researcher names. But then I added renderCell: to column of involvedResearchers the component what is used to render Cell non-stop mounts and unmounts. I left in useEffect console.log what triggers on component mount. And in console it shows 700 outputs, but I only have 3 records in DB.
Component used in renderCell on its mount call Api. Problem starts then by some reason do to component mount / unmount it calls thousand times to back-end at least until back-end collapses.

Component what works

```js
const DisplayNumberOfParticipants = ({ researchId }) => {
  const [participantsCount, setParticipantsCount] = React.useState(0);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const participantsCount = async() => {
      try {
        const activeParticipants = await researchService.getResearchParticipants(
          researchId,
          { status: ParticipantStatusEnum.Active }
        );
        setParticipantsCount(activeParticipants.length);
      } catch (error) {
        setParticipantsCount(0);
      }
    }

    participantsCount();
    console.log("IN UseEffect, DisplayNumberOfParticipants"); // Shows in console only three times
  }, []);

  return ( <p>{participantsCount}</p> );
```

This component is used for to display involved researchers names. User hovers on "..." and popout shows out with involved reserachers full names. Popover itself is outside of component it is alongside the Grid.

```js
const InvolvedResearchersCell = ({ researchDraftId, showPopOver, hidePopOver }) => {
  const [involvedResearchersFullNames, setInvolvedResearchersFullNames] = React.useState([]);
  const cellTextRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const getInvolvedResearchers = async() =>{
      try {
        const involvedResearchers = await researchService.getInvolvedResearchers(researchDraftId); 

        const fullNames = involvedResearchers.map((involvedResearcher)=>{ return `${involvedResearcher.name} ${involvedResearcher.surname}`;})
        setInvolvedResearchersFullNames(fullNames ); // if this line of code is removed all works fine, but I need data from API.
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    
    getInvolvedResearchers();
    console.log("IN UseEffect InvolvedResearchersCell"); // Shows in console many times
  });

  const cellMessage = () => {
    switch (involvedResearchersFullNames.length) {
      case 0:
        return "None";
      case 1:
        return involvedResearchersFullNames[0]
      default:
        return "..."
    }
  }
  const handleOnMouseEnter = () => {
    if (involvedResearchersFullNames.length > 1)
      showPopOver(involvedResearchersFullNames, cellTextRef.current)
  }
  const handleOnMouseLeave = () => {
    if (involvedResearchersFullNames.length > 1)
      hidePopOver();
  }
  return (<Typography
            ref={cellTextRef}
            onMouseEnter={handleOnMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={handleOnMouseLeave}
          >
            {cellMessage()}
            </Typography>
        );
};
```

Column definitions itself

```js
const columns = [
    {
      field: "dateCreated",
      headerName: "Created",
      editable: false,
      flex: 0.09,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        if (!params.value) return "";
  
        return timeUtil.date(params.value);
      },
    {
      field: "involvedResearchersIds",
      headerName: "Involved researchers.",
      flex: 0.09,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      editable: false,
      renderCell: (rowData) => <InvolvedResearchersCell  researchDraftId={rowData.row.id} />
            //showPopOver={handlePopoverOpen}
            //hidePopOver={handlePopoverClose}
           // researchDraftId={rowData.row.id}
        //  />

    },
    {
      field: "getSamples",
      headerName: "Samples",
      flex: 0.09,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      editable: false,
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        if (!params.value) return "";
  
        return params.value ? "Jā" : "Nē";
      },
    },
    {
      field: "id",
      headerName: "Active participants",
      flex: 0.09,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      editable: false,
  
      renderCell: (rowData) => <DisplayNumberOfParticipants researchId={rowData.row.id}/>
    },
  ];
```

DataGrid itself and Popover under it.

```js
        <Box display="flex" width="100%" justifyContent="center" height="100%">
          <DataGrid
            rows={gridData.rows}
            columns={columns}
            autoHeight
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
            onPageSizeChange={handlePageSizeChange}
            onCellClick={handleEditResearch}
            paginationMode="server"
            pagination
            page={gridData.page}
            pageSize={gridData.pageSize}
            rowCount={gridData.totalRows}
            loading={gridData.loading}
            rowsPerPageOptions={gridData.rowsPerPageOptions}
            slots={{
              NoRowsOverlay: NoRowsOverlay,
              NoResultsOverlay: NoRowsOverlay,
            }}
            componentsProps={{ pagination: { ...DataGridPaginationProps() } }}
          />
          <Popover
            sx={{
              pointerEvents: 'none',
            }}
            open={showPopOver}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'center',
            }}
            transformOrigin={{
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "center"
            }}
            onClose={handlePopoverClose}
            disableRestoreFocus
          >
            <List>
              {involvedResearchersFullNames && involvedResearchersFullNames.map((fullName, index) => {
                return (<ListItem key={index}>{fullName}</ListItem>);
              })}
            </List>
          </Popover>
        </Box>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vks4d.png)

I am expecting advice, how to solve this problem, what component somehow mounts/ unmounts infinite times.